# How to ignore comments while reading an XML file in Pyspark Databricks?

Tags: xml, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks, apache-spark-xml

I am trying to read an xml file in Azure Databricks Notebook in PySpark.
The problem is that my persons.xml has some comments in the beginning.
I just want to ignore them while reading the file.

```
df = spark.read
      .format("com.databricks.spark.xml")
      .option("rowTag", "person")
      .xml("src/main/resources/persons.xml")
```

My XML looks like this:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!-- 
<top>
       <t1 attr1="a1">
          <!-- t1 comment -->
          <t2>Something 1</t2>
       </t1>
       <!-- between rows comment -->
       <t1 attr1="a2">
          <t2>Something 2</t2>
       </t1>
    </top> 
    --> 
        <naman>
           <t1 attr1="a1">
              <t2>Something 1</t2>
           </t1>
           <t1 attr1="a2">
              <t2>Something 2</t2>
           </t1>
        </naman>
```

Answer (score 0):

Comments are ignored by default, if you see them, then it's something strange. for example, if I have following XML file:

```xml
<!-- top comment -->
<top>
  <t1 attr1="a1">
    <!-- t1 comment -->
    <t2>Something 1</t2>
  </t1>
  <!-- between rows comment -->
  <t1 attr1="a2">
    <t2>Something 2</t2>
  </t1>
</top>
```

then it's could be read as, and no comments are captured:

```py
>>> df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.xml") \
  .option("rowTag", "t1").load("1.xml")
>>> df.show()
+------+-----------+
|_attr1|         t2|
+------+-----------+
|    a1|Something 1|
|    a2|Something 2|
+------+-----------+
```

Comment: Actually the kind of XML which I have is a bit different from this.
In the XML above, the comments do not have XML tags within them. However, the XML which I have is similar to the below:

<!-- top comment 
<top>
  <t1 attr1="a1">
    <!-- t1 comment -->
    <t2>Something 1</t2>
  </t1>
  <!-- between rows comment -->
  <t1 attr1="a2">
    <t2>Something 2</t2>
  </t1>
</top>
-->

<naman>
  <t1 attr1="a1">
    <t2>Something 1</t2>
  </t1>
  <t1 attr1="a2">
    <t2>Something 2</t2>
  </t1>
</naman>

I want only tags outside the comment to be read, not ones within comment

Comment: Your XML isn't valid... Provide a sample of XML that you're trying to parse - add to your question

Comment: I have added the exact XML in the question.